# Image Address (URL) Not Available when Setting src to local file in windows server2008 R2 64

Tags: html, windows

I am having a problem setting an image's source property to refer to a local file when running the application under Windows 2008R2 64.

The application is running normally on 2008, XP and Win7, but when running the application under 2008R2 64 no image is displayed. Checking the source of the Page in IE and Chrome I can see the `src` property points to the correct location, but if I right click the image and view its properties all properties are Not Available.

Answer (score 1):

Select **Tools** - **Internet options** - **Security**
Select Internet zone, if it's not already selected
Click the **Custom level**... box
In the Settings window, scroll down to **Display mixed content** and select **Enable**
Click **OK** twice to close out the dropdowns

Hold shift and click refresh to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

First off, is the tag not `<img src...>` ? You said SCR so I just wanted to make sure you'd typed SCR on purpose or if that was a typo...

I've had the same problem debugging my websites in Visual Web Developer... The image tags all look right, I've even copied the source text (the address of the image) as reported by VWD without any improvement.

What I found was that the problem had to do with how I was specifying the path.
I prefer to use absolute paths from the web root, but it seems like some software doesn't like that, try a relative path from the page you're working on:

So instead of:

```
<img src="~/Images/header.png">
```

Use

```
<img src="../Images/header.png">
```

HTH

Comment: thanks Logan 
But that not the Issue the issue is when Image src is set to a local file on the Client Machine like "file:///C:\TempFiles\Image1.jpeg"
the Image will not Show in windows 2008R2 64  this work fine on windows 2008 , windows 7 and XP . further if you check the page source at runtime you can see the Image src point to the correct path on the Client Machine,if you right Click the Image and Select Properties  you will notice that the image have all its Properties  set to Not Available, I think its Security Issue with 2008R2 but I dont Know where to Look 
:(

Comment: It seems like a stupid question, but are you 100% sure that the image is actually there and that the name is exactly the same as what you're using (i.e. No spaces anywhere that you could be missing)?

It's also happened to me on occasion that although I had the location of a file right, I wasn't able to use it because of a Space in the filename that I was missing.

Unfortunately, I've never linked images with `file:///` so I can't help you there... Is there a specific reason you're doing it that way instead of using a more common path format?

Comment: I am 100% sure every thing is OK the Application run normally on windows 2008 and 7 and XP its only show this problem when browse the Application from windows 2008R2 , further investigations show its mostly a Security issue on 2008R2

Comment: Ok, well, if it's a security issue, then I'm going to have to step aside now and let someone else help you as I have next to no experiene working on Win Server 2008 R2...